# mixing two PHP carsto echo a single string value

Tags: php

I need to check if there is a product code in db else assign a product code starting with 101 and add 0001

I am trying like this

```
$store_code="101";
$product_code=($store_code(0001));
```

but I get a blank page ...

The result I need is 1010001

any sugestion is welcome

NOTE: the store code comes from MySQL but I show it now like this for an easier understanding

Comment: please post enough code to be able to verify the problem

Comment: Why the parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I get this correctly, you first check if the product code is in database, and you have no truble doing that.

```
//lets say $product_code is your code
//if code not in db:
$product_code .= "0001"; //this will add 0001 at the end of the $product_code variable
```

or

```
$product_code = $store_code . "0001";
```

Comment: I am glad! Feel free to upvote the answer and accept the answer! :D